# Android: TableLayout loses layout after switching with ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, alignment, tablelayout

I load a layout which among many things contains a TableLayout. The layout is part of a ViewSwitcher. I then switch to a different layout and then back to the original layout that had the TableLayout. The TableLayout loses its layout structure. The table had 2 columns and multiple rows. The cells in the second column were all aligned but upon returning after switching to another layout, the cells are no longer aligned. It seems that Android loses the layout when switching between views. Any suggestions on fixing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By setting android:stretchColumns on the TableLayout on the far right column, this fixed the problem.